# Reading JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file called 'elements.json':

```
[
{ldraw="003238a",lgeo="003238a",slope=0,anton=0,lutz=0,owen=0,damien=0},
{ldraw="003238b",lgeo="003238b",slope=0,anton=0,lutz=0,owen=0,damien=0},
{ldraw="003238c",lgeo="003238c",slope=0,anton=0,lutz=0,owen=0,damien=0},
{ldraw="003238d",lgeo="003238d",slope=0,anton=0,lutz=0,owen=0,damien=0}
]
```

I have a Python file called 'test.py':

```
import json

with open('elements.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data:
        print('ldraw: ' + p['ldraw'])
        print('lgeo: ' + p['lgeo'])
```

Running from the Windows command line I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 2 column 2 (char 3)
```

What property name is expected? Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Your json is not valid, for the assignment ":" is used and not "=". You could use the tool https://jsonlint.com/ to validate if your data is valid

Comment: Ahhh I was over here looking at load documentation trying to figure out if this was a weird syntax edge case. Good catch!

Comment: Sorry about the "-". That was actually already fixed in my JSON file, so it's not related to the error.

Comment: @posfan12 In addition, the keys must be strings, by example change `ldraw` to `"ldraw"`

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @posfan12 Do not edit your question to eliminate the cause of the problem, if you do then your question would no longer make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't following the JSON specification. See [json.org](http://json.org/) for details.

```json
[
  {"ldraw":"003238a","lgeo":"003238a","slope":0,"anton":0,"lutz":0,"owen":0,"damien":0},
  {"ldraw":"003238b","lgeo":"003238b","slope":0,"anton":0,"lutz":0,"owen":0,"damien":0},
  {"ldraw":"003238c","lgeo":"003238c","slope":0,"anton":0,"lutz":0,"owen":0,"damien":0},
  {"ldraw":"003238d","lgeo":"003238d","slope":0,"anton":0,"lutz":0,"owen":0,"damien":0}
]
```

Your Python code is correct.

---

Your `ldraw` and `lgeo` values *look* like hexadecimal; JSON does not support hex, and you will have to do the extra work yourself.
<sup>[Edit: They're not]</sup>

Comment: It's not hexadecimal. It's just a normal string.

Answer (score 1):

Your file elements.json is not a valid json file. 
It should have looked like this -

```
[{"ldraw":"003238a","lgeo":"003238a"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format is invalid, JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, like the Javascript Object. So, you should replace "=" to ":". It means key-value pairs.

Wrong:

```
ldraw="003238a"
ldraw: 003238a // if no quote, the value should be the digit only.
```

Right:

```
ldraw: "003238a"
ldraw: { "example-key": "value" }
ldraw: "True"
```